# AWK divide sum of column by number of lines in file

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk

I have a file which contains lines of data like below

```
300,,,292,15.4,0,04/16/12 20:10:39
200,,,292,15.4,0,04/16/12 20:10:39
100,,,292,15.4,0,04/16/12 20:10:39
```

Using awk i am summing up the first column like this

```
awk -F ',' '{ x = x + $1 } END { print x }' MyFile
```

Which is retuning 600 no problems.

I want to modify this command to also calculate the amount of lines in the file and then instead of `{ print x }` i want to `{ print x / y }` where y is the number of lines in the file.

So it would return 600 / 3 = 200.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of records processed so far is in NR:

```
awk -F, '{ x += $1 } END { print x " " x/NR }' MyFile
```

NR counts across all files processed; here, that's a single file.  There's also FNR in at least some versions of `awk`; that counts the number of records processed in the current file.  In this example, NR == FNR at all times because there's a single file.

Comment: It's worth noting that `NR` isn't the number of records in the file, just the ordinal number of the current record (in this case it's the last record, so everything works).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try NR for the [number of records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK#Built-in_variables)?

```
awk -F ',' '{ x = x + $1 } END { print x/NR }' MyFile
```